# Encryption of existing dataset in ZFS (ZoL 0.8)

Tags: filesystems, encryption, zfs

Is it possible to encrypt an existing dataset (including snapshots) in `ZFS on Linux >= 0.8`, e.g. by using `send | recv` and destruction of the original dataset?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is. See this simple example (tested on ZoL 0.8.3).

If you would like to use a raw keyfile (rather than a passphrase):

```
( umask 777
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/path/to/keyfile bs=32 count=1 )
```

Create a snapshot first:

```
zfs snapshot -r tank/home@transfer
```

Then, as proposed, `send | recv` (with replication option `-R`), but provide your encryption options on the receive side:

```
zfs send -R tank/home@transfer |
    zfs receive \
        -o encryption=aes-256-gcm \
        -o keyformat=raw \
        -o keylocation=file:///path/to/keyfile \
        tank/newhome
```

If the original dataset is mounted,
the new one will not be mounted straightaway:

> cannot mount '/tank/home': directory is not empty

Destroy the unencrypted dataset and replace it with your new one:

```
zfs destroy -r tank/home
zfs rename tank/newhome tank/home
```

If your dataset does not have any children, mounting is easy:

```
zfs mount tank/home
```

else

```
zfs list -rH -o name tank/home | xargs -L 1 zfs mount
```

(or simply `zfs mount -a` if you don’t have other datasets which should not be mounted).

And that was about it!

Finally, destroy the snapshot, if you like:

```
zfs destroy -r tank/home@transfer
```